# Creating a text parse for certain numbers

Tags: c#

I have a textbox that I want to use to detect certain numbers (1 - 65) that have a value attached to them for doing math with the value.

Example: When a user types in the numerals "50" I want to associate that with the value 4500 (50, 4500).

So for each number 1 - 65 I want to assign a specific value, then when a user types a number 1 - 65 the program takes the associated value and assigns that to a variable so I can do math.

```
int lvl50 = 4500;
lvl50 = clvl;

tolvl = clvl - currentexp;
int ttlvl = (tlvl / ptexp) +1;
```

I'm looking for something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use a `Dictionary<int,int>`

```
var values = new Dictionary<int,int> { { 1, 1000 }, { 50, 4500 } ... };
```

Then you can get the corresponding value of a number

```
values[50] // returns 4500
```

With user input:

```
var input = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
var value = values[input];
```

Or use `TryParse` and `ContainsKey` methods to avoid *possible* exceptions

```
int input = -1;
if(int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out input) && values.ContainsKey(input))
{
    var value = values[input];
}
```

Comment: Once I've got this, how do I assign the value "4500" to a variable?

Comment: @Advancin `int myVariable = values[50];`

Comment: You should use `TryParse` and `TryGetValue` to handle bad user input.

Comment: I've got it working with the original answer, but if I tr to use the `TryParse` and `TryGetValue` I get an error stating.

`clvl` conflicts with the declaration Leveling_Estimator.Form1.clvl

I'm not sure why.

Comment: I think the answer can be improved using `Dictionary<string,int>` that way you don't have to parse the text input, but you will have to deal with `IndexOutOfRangeException` (or what dictionary throws) if text is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

One of the methods I can think of is the use of a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` found under [System.Collections.Generic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx);
            values.Add(50, 4500);:

```
var values = new Dictionary<int, int>();
values.Add(50, 4500);
// ... etc
```

Answer (score 0):

**Create a formula/function:**
If the numbers 1-65 values have any formula, than you can use create a method that will implement that formula value in order to use it.

**Example:**

```
public static int myFormula(int number)
{
    return number * 90;
}
```

**Dictionary:**
If the following number matched values don't have any visible formula than you can use the `Dictionary<int, int>` to match them a specific value.

**Example:**

```
var myDic = Dictionary<int, int>() {
    new { 1, 1 },
    new { 50, 4500 },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code snippet, it looks (to me) like you may be calculating the value in the dictionary based on the key. You could place the logic for calculating the value in a separate method:

```
private int CalculateValue(int x)
{
    // calculate value and return it
}
```

Then create a dictionary for a particular range of numbers like this:

```
var dict = Enumerable.Range(1, 65).ToDictionary(x => x, CalculateValue);
```

To use an element from the dictionary, just reference it using the key:

```
var matchingValue = dict[50];  // Lookup key 50
```

If it's possible the key may not exist, you can test for it:

```
var value = dict.ContainsKey(72) ? dict[72] : -1;  // Assign some default value
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a dictionary like the other answers suggest will work for you, but if your numbers 1-65 have no gaps, you can use a list (or even a simple array). The index of the list will be your input. That will be easier and more efficient than a dictionary.

```
var values = new List<int> { 1000 , 4500 };
```

Then you can get the corresponding value of user input:

```
int input, value;
if(int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out input)){
  if(values.Contains(input){
    value = values[input];
  }
}
```